# Delete files & rows from a MySQL result set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Linux box which is capturing data, creating files, and storing data about the files in a MySQL table. I need to be able to start pruning that data selectively.

I was planning to use a php-cli script and run it nightly via cron.

The basic premise is to select rows which meet criteria for deletion, delete the files from the matching rows, then delete the rows. The path/filename is stored in the row.

I found the following query to safely select, then delete the rows, but I need to delete the files in the results as well from the file system:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE wee = 'yahoo!';
DELETE FROM bar WHERE wee = 'yahoo!';
COMMIT;
```

I know how I can delete the files using php's unlink() function. I'm just not sure how to preserve the result set, iterate through deleting files, then delete the result set rows from the table... without a big ugly hack of writing to a temporary text file or something.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT: PHP 5.3.6, MySQL 5.0.77

Comment: Ehm. I really do not see problems. Transaction ensures that it will SELECT and then DELETE that line, and `unlink();` function does work. What's your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a transaction if you are just launching 1 DELETE query.

```
<?php

    $pdo::prepare("SELECT [...]");
    foreach($result as $pathname) {
      unlink($pathname);
      if (/*everything went good*/)
        $pdo::prepare("DELETE [...]");
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually don't have a problem. You can just select all records and iterate over them. Once the query is executed, you can iterate over each record in the result set, even if you delete them using a second query. The resultset is kept in memory while you iterate over it.

So, just query (in one query if possble) all record that are to be deleted. In each iteration, delete the file and delete that record.

The only 'problem' is that the file system is not transacted in the same transaction as the SQL statement, so if there is an error while deleting the record, the file might still be deleted and vice versa.

Since I think the application that uses the files should always explicitly check if the file exists, it would be the best to clean-up the files first. If you delete the file first, check if it is deleted, and only then delete the record, you can make sure that the file is always deleted. If an error would occur while deleting the record, you can always query it again to try again. If you delete the record first, you may get a tree of accidentally not deleted files, needlessly taking up disk space.